# Parse json link to get the image

Tags: android, json

i am doing a project in which i have to get the image from the web server, the data is stored in json format. i have a json url, i have to get the names and image url's from the server and then get the bitmap images from the server.

Can anyone please help me in doing this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code for getting image drawable form the url

```
public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}  

private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url) {

    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```